# auto increment field in select query statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table with 2 columns, name and id with these following values

Name  Student_ID 
  jack      231
  dave      425
  mike      001
  lily      128
  liam      358

I would like to add a new column to this result with auto incremented sequence values.

I have tried using the below query. But i get a error as described below

Query:

```
    SELECT @n := @n +1 n,
           name, 
           id
      FROM table1, (SELECT @n := 0) m
     ORDER BY id

    Error: 
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":="
    LINE 2: SELECT @n := @n +1 n,
```

Expected Result:

```
    Name  Student_ID  Serial
     jack      231      1    
     dave      425      2
     mike      001      3  
     lily      128      4 
     liam      358      5
```

Comment: Are you really using Postgres?  Or, are you using MySQL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's Postgres, otherwise it would not be syntax error if it is MySQL. Perhaps he uses MySQL in past life

Comment: @MichaelBuen Well actually it is an error on MySQL too, because the table the OP described has no `id` column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hmm.. shouldn't it be "id field not found"?  Not syntax error?

Comment: That's a syntax error :-)

Comment: It's `id field not found`, to be exact `column id does not exist`, not a syntax error. I thought Posgtres is getting ridiculous that it will flag missing field as syntax error. So I tried: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2LuQVjh4PEiHvUNNnspFDF/0

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I focused on syntax error, it can be deduced it's MySQL if it don't have a syntax error, so I didn't deserve that `well actually` https://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `row_number()`

```
select name, student_id, row_number() over(order by student_id) as serial
from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number`, it works on Postgres

```
select *, row_number() over(order by id) as serial from table1
```

Your code `@n := @n + 1` is MySQL's work-around for its lack of windowing functions (e.g., `row_number`) on its older versions. The latest MySQL now has windowing functions. You can just merely use `row_number`, no need for work-around.

And you don't even need that work-around in Postgres. It has windowing functions long before almost everyone else

Answer (score 0):

try with `row_number()`

```
SELECT row_number()over(order by id) n,
           name, 
           id
      FROM table1 
     ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually looks to me to be MySQL, not Postgres code.  I do get your error running on Postgres, but Postgres typically does not allow user variables to be used in regular SQL queries anyway.  When running your query against MySQL, I get an error that the `id` column does not exist.

But, in any case, Postgres has supported the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function for a long time, so just use that instead:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Student_ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Student_ID) Serial
FROM table1
ORDER BY
    Student_ID;
```